# How can i generate qcelp

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, rtp, codec

For a project needs to generate `rtp pcap` with codec `qcelp`.
`ffmpeg` only can decode it but for send with `rtp ffmpeg` need encode with `qcelp`
I think software simulation in telecommunication use this codec
Do you know how can I generate `qcelp` traffic with `sip sdp`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1)I install virtualbox in my computer that my windows or Linux

2)I run mac os x snow leopadro as virtual machine in virtualbox

3)I install QuickTime Broadcaster in snow leopadro

4)With Quicktime Broadcaster i can generate RTP pcap with payloadtype Qcelp 12